# Error al realizar un Scroll con Appium Android

Tags: android, selenium, appium

Estoy intentanto realizar un scroll para una app con Appium en Intelij

```
    (new TouchAction(driver))
            .longPress(PointOption.point(572, 1314))
            .waitAction(waitOptions(ofSeconds(2)))
            .moveTo(PointOption.point(614, 531))
            .release()
            .perform();
```

ese es mi código y no realiza el scroll

Answer (score 0):

prueba con este codigo, a mi me funciono. Hace el scroll hasta la palabra "cambiar"

```
     MobileElement element = (MobileElement) 
     driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator(
                "new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true))" +
                        ".scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().text(\"cambiar\"))"));
```